# How to block USB ports on Live Ubuntu

Tags: live-usb, read-only

I want to give access to some person to see or read some materials on a system without letting him copy the material out of the system. So, I am thinking of blocking USB ports or at least force it to be mounted only in readonly mode.

I have gone through some solutions but all needed `update-initfs -u` and then system reboot.

How else I get the work done?

Comment: Live sessions are to be run as live only and that means settings will be lost.

Comment: I know. That is why I am asking this question to see if there is any method to achieve the aim without restarting the system

Comment: You can install Ubuntu into a USB drive (not a live system, but installed like into an internal drive). Such a system can be tweaked in a flexible way like any installed system). There are detailed tips in this link: [How do I install Ubuntu to a USB key? (without using Startup Disk Creator)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16988/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-to-a-usb-key-without-using-startup-disk-creator/942312#942312) -- But if the person brings an own live drive and boots from it, the system in the internal drive will be wide open unless it is encrypted.

Comment: This might be useful. If it works you may want to answer your own question explaining how you did it https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1958073&page=71&p=13670206#post13670206